# How do I add this `data-toggle-card` attribute to my link that has no Key/Value pair?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So this is the HTML link I am trying to recreate using `link_to`.

```
<a data-toggle-card data-card-id="1" data-card-title="Swimming in New York" data-card-description="Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.">
```

I can manage everything except for the first `data-toggle-card`.

For the rest, I have this:

```
link_to event.eventable.node.name, "#", data: {card_id: event.eventable.node.id, card_title: event.eventable.node.media.title, card_description: event.eventable.node.media.description
```

Notice I don't know how to tackle the `data-toggle-card` on the `link_to`.

How do I do this within the `link_to` helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `toggle_card: ""` in your data hash should work. It would look like:

`link_to event.eventable.node.name, "#", data: {card_id: event.eventable.node.id, card_title: event.eventable.node.media.title, card_description: event.eventable.node.media.description, toggle_card: ""}`

The `link_to` helper will output `data-toggle-card=""` but it should function properly. I don't believe there's a way to keep `=""` from being rendered with the `link_to` helper.